# Import csv file in drf

Tags: csv, django-rest-framework, django-import-export

I'm trying to create a view to import a csv using drf and django-import-export.

My example (I'm doing baby steps and debugging to learn):

```py
class ImportMyExampleView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser, )

    def post(self, request, filename, format=None):
        person_resource = PersonResource()
        dataset = Dataset()
        new_persons = request.data['file']
        imported_data = dataset.load(new_persons.read())
        return Response("Ok - Babysteps")
```

But I get this error (using postman):

```sh
Tablib has no format 'None' or it is not registered.
```

Changing to `imported_data = Dataset().load(new_persons.read().decode(), format='csv', headers=False)` I get this new error:

```sh
InvalidDimensions at /v1/myupload/test_import.csv
No exception message supplied
```

Does anyone have any tips or can indicate a reference? I'm following this [site](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/packages/2016/08/11/django-import-export.html), but I'm having to "translate" to drf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with baby steps is a great idea.  I would suggest get a standalone script working first so that you can check the file can be read and imported.

If you can set breakpoints and step into the django-import-export source, this will save you a lot of time in understanding what's going on.

A sample test function (based on the [example app](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#example-app)):

```py
def test_import():
    with open('./books-sample.csv', 'r') as fh:
        dataset = Dataset().load(fh)
    book_resource = BookResource()
    result = book_resource.import_data(dataset, raise_errors=True)
    print(result.totals)
```

You can adapt this so that you import your own data.  Once this works OK then you can integrate it with your `post()` function.

I recommend getting the example app running because it will demonstrate how imports work.

`InvalidDimensions` means that the dataset you're trying to load doesn't match the format expected by `Dataset`.  Try removing the `headers=False` arg or explicitly declare the headers (`headers=['h1', 'h2', 'h3']` - swap in the correct names for your headers).

Comment: Thank you very much for the guidance. I will do that.